# Validation Rule Error when converting a lead

Tags: validation-rule, lead-conversion

I have two picklist fields with dependencies in place. One is Lead Status and One is Status Subcategory. I have a VR so that forces the user to complete the Status Subcategory if the lead status is set to Marketing Qualified or Unqualified, but does not have Status Subcategory completed.

```
OR( 
(AND(ISPICKVAL( Status ,"Marketing Qualified" ),ISBLANK(TEXT( Status_Subcategory__c )) 
)), 
(AND(ISPICKVAL( Status ,"Unqualified" ),ISBLANK(TEXT( Status_Subcategory__c )) 
)) 
)
```

This VR is coming up during the lead conversion... not sure why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable validation rules on lead conversion

[Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331020&type=1&mode=1) -

> To enforce a Validation Rule when converting leads, you need to enable
>   'Require validation for Converted Leads.'
>
> Note: If the 'Require validation for Converted Leads' setting is not
>   available, please contact Salesforce Support to enable the 'Use Apex
>   Lead Convert' permission.

Comment: that did the trick.